# HTML5 background video keeps showing up, w media queries

Tags: css, html, wordpress, media-queries

So I have this background video on my wordpress CMS, and now I want to tell it to go into hiding on smaller devices, however; it keeps showing up. What is going wrong here? Here's the code:

```
.header-unit {
  height: 618px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  border-right:none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
#video-container {
position: absolute;
}

#video-container {
top:0%;
left:0%;
height:100%;
width:100%;
-webkit-filter: blur(7px);
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 3s ease;
-o-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease;
overflow: hidden;
}

#video-container:hover {
 -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
 -moz-opacity: 1;
 opacity: 1;
}
 video {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
 }
  video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 0px)
.video-container {
    background:none;!important
}
```

By the way I've seen similar questions asked but the answers didn't help me :-)

And here's the HTML :

```
<div class="header-unit">
<div id="video-container">
<video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
<source src=".../uploads/2015/03/test.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
</div><!-- end video-container -->
</div><!-- end .header-unit -->
```

Comment: Your media queries are targeting .video-container class not #video-container id?

Comment: Could you post the related HTML as well?

Comment: Oops yeah you're right, tried going a different route with it and forgot to change it back. It also doesn't work when targeting the id

Comment: easy mistake to make - we all go blind staring at code sometimes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your media queries are targeting .video-container class not #video-container id and your video is a html element not a background element

Change

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 0px)
.video-container {
background:none;!important
}
```

to

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 0px)
#video-container {
    display:none;!important
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)), that should normally do the job :( But that darn video is still showing up!

Comment: Do you have a live preview I can see?

Comment: I just looked at that again - you need to hide the whole div as the video isn't a 'background' element - sorry, answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Try using `#video-container` instead of `.video-container` in your media query.